# Where app such as Redlaser getting barcode databases of commercial items?

Tags: barcode

I know about http://www.upcdatabase.com/, but it's quite incomplete. Where popular mobile apps getting barcode dbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for RedLaser -- we've built our own product database from thousands of different sources. A lot of it comes directly from retailers and manufacturers.

Comment: Do you plan to provide access to DB as a service?